# Class with search facility in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand JavaScript correctly. I need your valuable comments to clear my understanding. Say I have two class as follows:

```
var Student = function (code, fullName, department) {
    this.code = code;
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.department = department;
}

var Department = function (id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Now the above two classes has a relation with `department id`. I am trying to write some function that verify the `department id` of `Department` class. And I am also trying to write couple of function to search data from these class such as `getStudent()`, `getStudentById()`.

But I can't understand what will be the best approach to do this. Any type of suggestion or tutorial link will be great help for me.

Comment: We're here to help with programming problems, not teach you how to use a language. So... start reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Just want to note, since you say you are trying to understand JS. Javascript doesn't have Classes, these are just functions, but you can mimic classes pretty closely, which is fine. Do you know how to attach methods to the prototype of a function? Just don't want to write up a basic answer if you do already know some of this stuff...